# I accidentally ripped out an eyelet/pth to my PCB when changing LED lights on a mechanical keyboard

Tags: pcb, through-hole

I accidentally ripped out an eyelet/pth to my PCB when changing LED lights on a mechanical keyboard. I'm am a beginner to anything like this so please use layman's terms. Please site places I can use to buy materials for the repair and possibly some good sources of information demonstrating how to.

[image: Bottom]
[image: Top]

Comment: put in a new LED and solder from both sides and test

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Do what jsotola said. Use the new LED leads behind the board to mend the connection. Solder the back side only.

Comment: I did exactly that but the solder doesn't want to stick to the board because the metal from the hole ripped out. It just beads up and floats over the hole. It's not the LED that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check the continuity from the popped out soldering point by looking carefully for remaining conductive path and check any other contacts its connected to so that u can bring a wire from that point to your led's leg by using insulated wires or enameled copper wire.

Answer (score 0):

Use a better braid or solder sucker next time and use AWG30 for replacing any broken track connections.. I suspect one connection top left is OK and bottom layer  right not shown is the other track.  Use a DMM to check continuity.

The "eyelet" sections may be called side 1 track, annular ring,> via ( or plated thru hole , PTH) <, annular ring, side 2 track. Check for solder shorts too.

Comment: If it's a multi-layer it may be pretty hard to tell where it is supposed to connect to...

Comment: component density may not need more than 2

Comment: Chances are the pad only connects to the LED, and the through-hole plating isn't required. Just solder a new LED in and see if it works!

Comment: Indeed, was just a general comment about how a simple mistake can make a multi-layer board unfixable if you do not have a schematic.